# Joomla! - Which file contains the registration codes?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, registration

I'm developing this website with Joomla! 1.5.22

I want to look for the file which contains the codes for registration as I want to see which table of the MySQL database is storing the users' information.
The reason I want to know this is because I have this mass-registration function which allows the reading of csv file and updating the database from the contents of the csv file.

So, I wish to know which table of the database is for the users' registration then I can proceed.

Can someone tell me how to locate the php file in my Joomla site folder that contains the codes for registration?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see two Joomla installations with the table jos_users. The default install only contains a handful of tables, just view them in phpMyAdmin if you don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table in Joomla database storing user information is `jos_users`(where **jos** may be replaced by the database prefix you had set during Joomla installation). There is no file in Joomla site folder for this, the user registration information is fully stored in `jos_users` database table. Let us know if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway do you know which PHP file does the SQL-insert-statements for the registration part?

Comment: Ya sure, its done in the com_user component of Joomla. Entry point is `save()` function [`<joomla_installation_folder>/components/com_user/controller.php`] function in the controller.php file, which calls `store()`function [`<joomla_installation_folder>/components/com_user/models/user.php`] from its model, in which actual insertion takes place.

Comment: There's only user.xml, author.xml and registered.xml in [<joomla_installation_folder>/components/com_user/models]. I also can't find the codes that calls store() function in the save() function of [<joomla_installation_folder>/components/com_user/controller.php].

Comment: Oops.. There seems to be something wrong. I have only Joomla 1.5.24 with me. Even then the structure you told seems different. Don't know why its so. In any case its within com_user that the insertion takes place.

Comment: I've checked the jos_users table and found out that it only contains the fields for id, name, username, email, password, etc.. It does not contain the other details such as the country, address, phone number, etc..